# Is there a way when the user exits the workbook without saving it resets to the original screen size?

Tags: vba

I have inserted the following code into the 'This Workbook' object to auto size a workbook when the user opens the file:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

Thsi worked a treat except once the spreadsheet is closed, the next time you open excel it auto sizes to your screen.

Is there a way when the user exits the spreadsheet without saving it resets to the original screen?

Comment: You can use the `WorkBook.BeforeClose` event, possibly in combination with the `BeforeSave` event. You can resize Excel before closing the workbook so it qwill be opened the next time in the normal/previous size.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I will do some research into that.